# Runtime onClicklLstener android

Tags: android, view, runtime, onclicklistener

Just wondering can anyone solve this problem about adding listeners to imagebuttons at runtime. I'm presuming it has got something to do with the "this" parameter passed to setOnClickListener as we are already in a onClickListener.

My fragment implements onclicklistener. The onClick methods work for imagebuttons known at compile time, just not for the ones that are defined after inflating a prompt view. What seems to happen is the prompt layout seems to be recreated and added onto the back stack.

Basically the onclicklistener for mWhatsappshare,mEmail share does not react as I might expect. I put a stackoverflow error in the onclick method previously and when I clicked these imagebuttons my application did not crash. This means that the listener is in fact not registered (or at least not correctly) at

```
mwhatsapp.setonclicklistener(this)
```

By the way, I do not want to set separate listener like mWhatsapp.setonclicklistner(new View.onClickListener()){ for each imagebutton as it is too cumbersome and I want each listener to be handled in onclick().

Thank you

```
mOtherShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeColorFilters();
            mOtherShare.setImageResource(R.drawable.other_pill_pressed);

            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_prompt,null);

            mWhatsappShare = (ImageButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.ib_whatsapp_share);
            mEmailShare = (ImageButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.ib_email_share);
            mFlickrShare = (ImageButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.ib_flickr_share);
            mTumblrShare = (ImageButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.ib_tumblr_share);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

            builder.setView(dialoglayout);
            dlg = builder.show();
            mWhatsappShare.setOnClickListener(this);
            mEmailShare.setOnClickListener(this);
            mFlickrShare.setOnClickListener(this);
            mTumblrShare.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    });
}


   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.ib_whatsapp_share:
               sendIntent("com.whatsapp");
               break;
            case R.id.ib_email_share:
               sendIntent("android.email");
               break;
            case R.id.ib_flickr_share:
                sendIntent("com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.flickr");
            break;
            case R.id.ib_tumblr_share:
            sendIntent("com.tumblr");
            break;
        }

}






``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this block of code:

```
        mWhatsappShare.setOnClickListener(this);
        mEmailShare.setOnClickListener(this);
        mFlickrShare.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTumblrShare.setOnClickListener(this);
```

`this` is referring to the new `OnClickListener` you are creating - `mOtherShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` and NOT your fragment's OnClickListener

To use the outer onClick, change `this` to `YourFragment.this`